# R functions to HTML

Tags: html, r, shiny

Not sure why there is an issue here. I am trying to convert R functions to HTML and then get the output, But no luck......................................................

Below reprex. Not sure why method 2 is not working

Method 1 : Working

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  htmlOutput("res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res <- renderUI({
    
    ## method 1
    fluidRow(column(3,plotlyOutput("p1")),
    column(3,plotlyOutput("p2")))
    
    ## method 2
    
    # HTML(cat('<div class="row">\n',paste(sapply(c("p1","p2"),
    #                                             function(i) as.character(tags$div(class="col-sm-3",
    #                                                                               tags$div(id=i, style="width:100%; height:400px;",
    #                                                                                class="plotly html-widget html-widget-output shiny-report-size shiny-report-theme")))),
    #                                      collapse="\n")))
  })
  
  output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly()
  })
  
  output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Method 2 : Not working (Though both are same)

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  htmlOutput("res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res <- renderUI({
    
    ## method 1
    # fluidRow(column(3,plotlyOutput("p1")),
    # column(3,plotlyOutput("p2")))
    
    ## method 2
    
    HTML(cat('<div class="row">\n',paste(sapply(c("p1","p2"),
                                                function(i) as.character(tags$div(class="col-sm-6",
                                                                                  tags$div(id=i, style="width:100%; height:400px;",
                                                                                   class="plotly html-widget html-widget-output shiny-report-size shiny-report-theme")))),
                                         collapse="\n")))
  })
  
  output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly()
  })
  
  output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `htmltools::findDependencies(plotlyOutput(""))` to attach plotly.js
2. use `paste0` instead of `cat`

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmltools::findDependencies(plotlyOutput("")),
  htmlOutput("res")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res <- renderUI({
    
    ## method 1
    # fluidRow(column(3,plotlyOutput("p1")),
    # column(3,plotlyOutput("p2")))
    
    ## method 2
    
    HTML(paste0('<div class="row">\n',paste(sapply(c("p1","p2"),
                                                function(i) as.character(tags$div(class="col-sm-6",
                                                                                  tags$div(id=i, style="width:100%; height:400px;",
                                                                                           class="plotly html-widget html-widget-output shiny-report-size shiny-report-theme")))),
                                         collapse="\n")))
  })
  
  output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly()
  })
  
  output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```